# Get unique values query with latest entries

Tags: database, group-by, hive

I am trying to write a query to get unique transaction values, with the sale value and the latest date that took place.

Here is my query:

```
select transaction, sales, max(sale_date) from xyz_table where report_date = 20160718 group by transaction, sales;
```

This is the result that i get:
This is the sample data:

```
|transaction     |     sales| sale_date| report_date|
|1397115220084030|  0.000144|   20160714|20160718|
|13971230534538500| 0       |   20160716|20160718|    
|13973937437448300| 0.000001|   20160716|20160718|    
|13976744119997000| 0.008563|   20160714|20160718|    
|13976744119997000| 0.002392|   20160715|20160718|
```

What i wanted was unique transactions with the latest sale date:
This is the required data:

```
|transaction     |     sales| sale_date| report_date|
|1397115220084030|  0.000144|   20160714|20160718|
|13971230534538500| 0       |   20160716|20160718|    
|13973937437448300| 0.000001|   20160716|20160718|    
|13976744119997000| 0.002392|   20160715|20160718|
```

I have tried to do max of sales but that still does not give the correct result:

```
select transaction, Max(sales), max(sale_date) from xyz_table where report_date = 20160718 group by transaction;
```

Wrong result:
This is the required data:

```
|transaction     |     sales| sale_date| report_date|
|1397115220084030|  0.000144|   20160714|20160718|
|13971230534538500| 0       |   20160716|20160718|    
|13973937437448300| 0.000001|   20160716|20160718|    
|13976744119997000| 0.008563|   20160715|20160718|
```

Please can someone help me.

Thanks

Comment: You should group by sale_date instead of transaction. Grouping by transaction results with all rows because the transaction numbers are all unique. Grouping by sale_date will return only one row for a given date.

Comment: Are you using Hive or MySQL?  These are quite different.

Comment: Sorry about that.. its a hive query.

Answer (score 1):

In Hive, you would use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by transaction order by sale_date desc) as seqnum
      from transactions t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The MySQL query would be quite different, because it does not support this ANSI standard functionality.